# Override Azure TestHub Shared test parameters

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, microsoft-test-manager

Hello we are using AzureDevOps and using the TestHub aspect we have started playing around with shared Test parameters.

We found that if we set value to Shared parameters we cannot override them in the test case. Are we doing something wrong, or is this as designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test case cannot override the shared parameters' value, But shared parameters can override the local parameters' value of the test cases. 
It seems like by design. You can check the [microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/repeat-test-with-different-data?view=azure-devops) about shared parameter.

You submit a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) or report a problem about this issue and ask microsoft development team to change this behavior of shared parameters.